# What does "To weep into stones are fables" mean?

Tags: meaning

The above words are taken from Thomas Browne's *Urn Burial* (1658), in this context:
"... Sense endureth no extremities, and sorrows destroy us or themselves. To weep into stones are fables. Afflictions induce callosities; miseries are slippery, or fall like snow upon us, which notwithstanding is no unhappy stupidity. ..."

Please, could you tell me only how you understand this part: "To weep into stones are fables." Is it the purpose of fables to weep into stones: "Fables are (made) to weep into stones"?

Or rather: "The weeping into stones is a/only exists in fable/s" (weeping into stones meaning to hollow a rock with one's tears).

Is there, or has there even been an idiom "to weep into stones"?

Answer (score 1):

According to [one version of the book with footnotes](https://books.google.com/books?id=kxR8gMNyXtIC&pg=PA177&lpg=PA177&dq=weep%20into%20stones%20fables%20like%20snow&source=bl&ots=QpwRc42T_M&sig=gMYsZZEF_XR_ZhPBGcBEzNs2pbs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcxdnrt-3eAhXEl-AKHR-6BOI4ChDoATAFegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=weep%20into%20stones%20fables%20like%20snow&f=false), this refers to the fable of Niobe:

> Devastated, Niobe fled back to Mount Sipylus and was turned into stone, and, as she wept unceasingly, waters started to pour from her petrified complexion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niobe

Compare with the quotes here: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/niobe

Comment: How do you explain the grammar of that sentence?

Comment: It is incorrect, taking "stones" to determine the verb. A very common mistake.

Comment: I think it's trying to make 'to be' agree with the apparent complement, 'fables'.

Comment: I think that this answer and user328747's followup answer are correct. I interpret the wording "To weep into stones are fables" as an unusually compact form of "The capacity of people to metaphorically weep themselves into stones (that is, to abandon themselves so completely to grief that they become as dead to the world of living things as stone is) is a fable (that is, an exaggerated circumstance not to be found in the real world)."

Answer (score 1):

As @Laurel correctly put it, it is a reference to the fable of Niobe.

Fables are fictional stories. So the phrase 'To weep into Stones are fables' is alluding to the fact that things that are impossible to happen are merely told in fables and are not realities. (It is impossible for stones to weep. In the fable of Niobe, not only did she turn into stone, her incessant weeping still continued after her petrification)

Answer (score 0):

'To weep into stones are fables'.

Firstly we ought to tackle for first infinitive clause: 'to weep into stones'. This is alluding, as others have pointed out, to the fable of Niobe who wept so much that she turned into stone.

The construction of the sentence with 'are' is more tricky to deal with. It appears that the author has tried to make the copula agree with the word 'fables' which is plural. Normally, the infinitive phrase would be considered the subject and the word 'fables' the subject complement. It appears that this element of the English grammar is somewhat confused, as it is difficult to determine whether the singular or the plural ought to be used. If we use the singular,

'To weep into stones is fables' or 'to weep into stones is a fable',

we find the former to be obviously wrong but the latter to be correct. If we flip the sentence around, we find,

'Fables are to weep into stones'.

It might, therefore, be an example of hyperbaton where the normal word order of the sentence has been manipulated for poetic effect, or possibly just an example of 17th century English. It seems the sentence is saying that one example of a fable is to weep so as to turn into stone, but in a more compact and poetic manner. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had never heard that phrase.  I take it to be a poetic equal of: "fables are to weep into stones", meaning that non-factual stories are ineffective or ultimately useless, just watering rocks with one's tears.

It may be a somewhat obfuscated way of indicating the author doesn't believe in in life after death.